# In KDE, stop virtual desktop changing when I click on the desktop

Tags: linux, kde, virtual-desktop, kde-4

I'm new to KDE and am running KDE 4.7.1 on top of Arch Linux. It's fantastic however I have one problem - virtual desktops. Yeah I know there are those "activities" things which people say replace virtual desktops and I will look into them, but for the moment I want to stick with what I know.

And it's almost set up too. In fact, it is, apart from one issue:

Say I'm on desktop 3 and I click on the desktop (as in - the bit with my wallpaper, etc, not the little square in my panel) - it immediately switches to desktop 1.

Got no idea why I'd want it to do that and it's bugging me.

Any ideas on how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I fixed it. Kind-of anyway. I switched to the desktop icon activity and suddenly it's fine.

Comment: You can mark this as the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.